# Change date format (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var fd=1+self.theDate.getMonth() +'/'+ today+'/'+self.theDate.getFullYear();
```

It works, but it's format is Month, Day, Year.

I need to change it to: Day, Month Year.

So, I tried this:

```
var fd=1+today +'/'+ self.theDate.getMonth()+'/'+self.theDate.getFullYear();
```

Now, my change does not work. Is it that I have not done it properly or is my change right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the correct answer is this:

```
var fd=today +'/'+ (self.theDate.getMonth() + 1) +'/'+self.theDate.getFullYear();
```

This leaves today alone, and groups Month so that it does a proper number addition instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theDate = new Date();
var today = theDate.getDate();
var month = theDate.getMonth()+1; // js months are 0 based
var year = theDate.getFullYear();
var fd=today +'/'+ month +'/'+year
```

or perhaps you prefer 22/05/2011

```
var theDate = new Date();
var today = theDate.getDate();
if (today<10) today="0"+today;
var month = theDate.getMonth()+1; // js months are 0 based
if (month < 10) month = "0"+month;
var year = theDate.getFullYear();
var fd=""+today +"/"+ month +"/"+year
```

Answer (score 1):

You are no longer adding `1` to the month, you are adding it to `today`. Make sure to parenthesize this since `"x" + 1 + 2 => "x12"` but `"x" + (1 + 2) => "x3"`